# Need to recreate an activity when the child activity returns

Tags: android

I have a problem with a third party activity I'm descending from (lets call that `ActivityA`. From A I launch another activity, `ActivityB` then when they close B it goes back to `ActivityA`.

`ActivityA` is not well written W.R.T. to the activity lifecycle and sometimes has an opengl exception when resuming from `ActivityB`. It never has the problem when starting a fresh.

I'd rather circumvent the exception rather than attempt to fix it by always reseting the activity.

How can I in effect `finish()` `ActivityA` but not remove it from the activity stack? Or is there a flag that will tell android to always destroy the activity when it disappears from view?

Comment: Not that is not possible, but you can do it other way around, start `ActivityB` with the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to clear the activity stack and when it is time to return to `ActivityA` just start a new `ActivityA` with a new `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the state of `ActivityA` from `ActivityB`. In your case since you cannot modify `ActivityA` I am not sure what kind of solution is applicable to you, but since as you describe `ActivityA` has to start your `ActivityB` I assume that you have to at least some control over this part. This solution assumes that in this case you are only dealing with 2 `Activities`, namely `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. It needs some extra work if your navigation hierarchy is bigger than that.

---

## **1) Basic Solution**

What you can do is start `ActivityA` with the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to clear the activity stack. This ensures that `ActivityA` has to be completely recreated and go through its complete lifecycle when you open it again. Your code to start `ActivityB` should look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But the drawback of this solution is that `ActivityB` will be the only `Activity` in the stack and therefore the default back functionality will not work. What you have to do to fix that is override `onBackPressed()` in `ActivityB` and from there launch `ActivityA` again. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You again need the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to fix your activity stack. Otherwise you could navigate from the `ActivityA` back to the `ActivityB` when pressing back after you return from `ActivityB`. You may also need to implement up navigation in a special way if `ActivityB` contains an `ActionBar` and up navigation is enabled:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Another drawback of this solution (although a minor cosmetic one - which can be fixed with some work) is that the animations used when going back to `ActivityA` will not be the animation which is played when finishing an `Activity` but instead the animation for opening a new `Activity`.

If that all looks a little like a hack to you than that's because it is. You are not supposed to modify the activity stack like that. The only reason you have to do this is because `ActivityA` is not properly implemented. Fixing `ActivityA` should be first priority but if that's impossible you might not get around implementing a workaround like I suggest here.

---

## **2) Better Solution:**

If you use the support library I would recommend you to use the `NavUtils` to navigate back to `ActivityA`. The `NavUtils` fix a few problems with the solution above, namely they make the animation issue a little better - altough it isn't fixed completely and it manages the activity stack for you. It works like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

## **3) Even better Solution**

If possible I would recommend that you define a parent for all `Activities` which have a predefined parent in the manifest with `android:parentActivityName` like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.ui.activities.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

If you use the support library you also need to add a meta tag with the name `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY` and the value being again the package name of the parent `Activity`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.ui.activities.MainActivity">
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.app.ui.activities.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

The advantage you get from defining a parent is that you don't have to manage the navigation, activity stack or anything yourself. If you set the parent of `ActivityB` as being `ActivityA` you can use the `NavUtils` and simply call `navigateUpFromSameTask(...)`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good, I'll give that a go. ActivityA only descends from third party activity, so I do have control of that part. I'll try to fix the bug later, but time pressures are such I need a quick fix first.

Comment: I have modified my answer with additional information and solutions. If possible use solution #3 otherwise #2. If both of those are not suitable for your needs you can still achieve it with solution #1.

Comment: Thanks I used solution 3 it works. I tried `android:noHistory="true"` on `ActivityA` too, it didn't seem to make any odds, but felt like the thing to do. Should I do that?

Comment: Yes, adding it seems reasonable. I'm glad I could help!